# org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: failed to locate current segments_N

Tags: lucene, indexing

I am getting following exception when loading spring container. The stack trace is as follows. It was working fine but don't know what happened. can any one gave me solutions for this

org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: failed to locate current segments_N

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated, it seems that your index has become corrupted.  A couple possible causes might be not closing resources correctly, or forcefully interrupting Lucene while it was writing to the index.

You can use [`CheckIndex`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html) to get more information about the state of the index, and attempt to fix it.